# PHP Time Timetable

Tags: php

```
<?php
    $test = strtotime("Monday");
    $testtime = date('N', $test);
    $time =  date('N', $test);

    for( $testtime = 1; $testtime <= 7; $testtime++ ) {
        echo date('l', $time); 
    }
?>
```

So I want to build a timetable that can have `timezones` applied so I need to build all the day and times with php time functions currently this code is supposed to echo monday-sunday but it only echo's one day. Is there anyway to build the days and time hour by hour and have a

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
```

apply to both of them.

Comment: What exactly are you after here - you mention a 'timetable' - with days hour by hour... - it's unclear to me.

Comment: Hey paul did some testing with what dateperiod I was wondering if there is away to get a value per interval?

http://codepad.org/URhLd5NI

So Can I get a day and time value?

Comment: for each iteration of the loop you are running `echo date('l', $time); ` yet you never change `$time` so it will always output the same thing.